# Can we do the OLE Automation in .NET?

Tags: vb.net, ole, vb6-migration

I have been working for vb to vb.net migrated project.In VB we have a OLE Container to show the word document and pdf also. I would like to know, do we have anything like this to show the word documents or PDF documents ?

I have read in the some of the forums the OLE Automation is not present in VB.NET.

Comment: It is not.  Office doesn't support it anymore either.

Comment: But we need to extend the Old VB Application functionalities in the new app also.

Answer (score -1):

OLE Automation was present in VB.NET as of .NET 4.0 -- I've used it to export data to Excel.

I'm not sure, but I think you need to link the appropriate libraries through the "COM" tab rather than the ".NET" tab in Visual Studio.